# What causes the 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )' in this code example?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Why am I getting this error message when running the code below.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>read json</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var load = function() {
      var data='{"took": 2,"timed_out": false,"_pieces": {  "total": 5,  "successful": 5,  "failed": 0},"hits": {  "total": 117,  "max_score": 0,  "hits": []},"aggregations": {  "2": {    "doc_error": 228,    "sum_other_t": 10705,    "buckets": [      {        "key": "2016",        "count": 196      },      {        "key": "2015",        "count": 163      },      {        "key": "2014",        "count": 159      },      {        "key": "2013",        "count": 157      },      {        "key": "2012",        "count": 157      }    ]  }}}';
      var myData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(myData.aggregations.2.buckets.length) ;   
      //console.log(myData) ;   
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
hi
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can drop that "JSON" directly into your JavaScript code with no need to parse it via `JSON.parse`; it's just an object literal.

Comment: 1) You need to use `[2]` instead of `.2` - 2) You don't need to parse anything, it's already valid syntax (hence the name: JSON = JavaScript Object Notaction), so you just need `var myData = {"took": 2, .....};`

Comment: I'm guessing the user has pasted a JSON server response into the example to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the docs **[dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation)** can only use when

> In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

---

So you need to use [bracket notation(`[]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property `2`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>read json</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var load = function() {
      var data = '{"took": 2,"timed_out": false,"_pieces": {  "total": 5,  "successful": 5,  "failed": 0},"hits": {  "total": 11537,  "max_score": 0,  "hits": []},"aggregations": {  "2": {    "_upper_bound": 228,    "doc_count": 10705,    "buckets": [      {        "key": "2016",        "count": 196      },      {        "key": "2015",        "count": 163      },      {        "key": "2014",        "count": 159      },      {        "key": "2013",        "count": 157      },      {        "key": "2012",        "count": 157      }    ]  }}}';
      var myData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(myData.aggregations[2].buckets.length);
      //console.log(myData) ;   
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
  hi
</body>

</html>
```

---

**FYI :** Also there is no need to define it as a JSON string, it's also a valid object format in JavaScript you can define it as object.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>read json</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var load = function() {
      var data = {"took": 2,"timed_out": false,"_pieces": {  "total": 5,  "successful": 5,  "failed": 0},"hits": {  "total": 11537,  "max_score": 0,  "hits": []},"aggregations": {  "2": {    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 228,    "sum_other_doc_count": 10705,    "buckets": [      {        "key": "2016",        "count": 196      },      {        "key": "2015",        "count": 163      },      {        "key": "2014",        "count": 159      },      {        "key": "2013",        "count": 157      },      {        "key": "2012",        "count": 157      }    ]  }}};
      console.log(data.aggregations[2].buckets.length);
      //console.log(myData) ;   
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
  hi
</body>

</html>
```